# Javascript 2D image pixel collision check

Tags: java, javascript, html

Im trying to get pixel collision in one of the games im working on. 
It has to be a pixel collision on one row of pixels on the X axis.
One of the things I tryed was:

var imgData = context2D.getImageData(160, 0, 3, Height);

And Height is afcorse the canvas height.
But this gives me a Security error" code: "1000.
This only happens if I put this script in front of my Draw function.

Can anybody help me out with this one?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using a drawImage() somewhere in your draw function with an image not on the same domain. Calling getImageData after drawing an image from another source will result in that error.

Comment: Yes im using drawImage() but the images are drawn in the same script and are lokated in the same folder. Is there a other way to draw images to the canvas then?

Comment: Is this a script on your own machine opened through file://? When running a script from file:// you will always receive this error as there is no domain.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this. Or is this only in my own file:// and if I put it on a server it will be gone?? Because it hase to go online in the future.

Comment: On the server it won't happen.If you're developing the script that way, you can add netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead"); in FireFox for now to make it work for you through file://